# Caddy reverse proxy, prioritize files, then reverse_proxy

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I got trouble using Caddy v2, while in v1 I never have such trouble

I want to prioritize:

```
file_server if started with /upload/*
reverse_proxy to 127.0.0.1:9090 if started with /api/*
else reverse_proxy to 127.0.0.1:3000
```

But seems I cannot get it properly work using v2, I've tried a lot (with matchers, changing port because `127.0.0.1` always 404 but localhost didn't, etc) but seems the `127.0.0.1:3000` always prioritized instead of `file_server` even when file exists, because it have wildcard?

```
{
        debug
        auto_https off
        log {
                output stdout
                level DEBUG
        }
        local_certs
}

127.0.0.1:80, localhost:80 {
        root ./svelte/dist
        file_server /upload/* browse
        reverse_proxy /api/* 127.0.0.1:9090
        reverse_proxy * 127.0.0.1:3000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, got the answer
https://caddy.community/t/v2-hard-to-make-it-right/13394/2

```
127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1:80, localhost, localhost:80 {
        handle /upload/* {
                root ./svelte/dist
                file_server browse
        }

        handle /api/* {
                reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:9090
        }

        handle {
                reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:3000
        }
}
```